# What image does our new theme need for the captcha page?

Tags: discussion, theme

What image does our new theme need for the captcha page?

Pretty simple.

Be creative people!

Comment: Do you have a link where logged in users can see this page?

Comment: Yes, there is one, http://dba.stackexchange.com/captcha

Comment: Are we still looking for a new image? I'd post this in the Heap to get some more eyes on it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand JNK changed his avatar. We probably have to use Johnny 5 now.

Comment: (@AaronBertrand: the "new" theme dates from Aug. 2011, according to this Q's timestamp)

Comment: @Mat Oh balls. I didn't even look at the Q's timestamp; I thought it was asked today.

Comment: Ok, let me try again: What's (still) wrong with the blue HAL?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: You could always post the existing image as an answer if you like it :-) (I'd vote for it.)

Answer (score 7):

Quick and dirty ([click to embiggen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLEc1.png)). This is just the concept - since we don't seem to be afraid of using copyrighted images (e.g. meta and main both use Flight of the Concords). I would also color the HAL blue to better match our theme.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Maybe not the best or most creative but....

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### 0 rows returned.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a pic of Master Control with the caption END OF LINE.

Answer (score 2):

Or how about a pic of Tron with the caption GREETINGS PROGRAMS! (Yes, I know it was Kevin Flynn who said it...but Tron is cooler....)